# Interpreting the Jaro-Winkler Score in Perl -- Are there Alternatives in Stata?

Tags: perl, statistics, stata, jaro-winkler

Is there an industry standard for how large the Jaro-Winkler score should be to say that the two strings are likely similar?

I have a list of strings and I want to see if any of them are plausible typographical errors for the name James.  I have used the perl module that was written in C, and in turn, whose strings I received from a dataset in stata.  (So if there were a Stata module, I'd be all ears!)

Here is the code that I wrote so far in perl to make the comparisons to the string James.

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

   use 5.10.0;
   use Text::JaroWinkler qw( strcmp95 );
   use List::Util qw(min max);

   open( my $l,  '<', 'Strings.txt' )          or die "Can't open locations: $!";
   open( my $o,  '>', 'JW.txt' )          or die "Can't open locations: $!";

   while ( my $line = <$l> ) {
    chomp($line);
    my $length = min(length($line),length('James'));
    my $jarow = strcmp95($line, 'JAMES', $length);
    print "$line,'JAMES',$jarow,\n" ;
    print( $o ("$line,'JAMES',$jarow"),"\n" );

  }
close $o;
```

I'm also not sure whether I'm interpreting the 3rd parameter of the Jaro-Winkler function appropriately or effectively.  Perhaps I should be doing length('JAMES') ?

Comment: (I removed the C tag, since this question isn't about C code and the module being written in C is irrelevant unless you're actually trying to modify it)

Comment: @user2096518: The answer to that lies in the Perl module and is independent of the XS source. The two strings you pass are pre-processed by changing their lengths to the value of the third parameter. Longer strings are truncated and shorter ones are padded on the right with spaces. You should change your `min` to `max`.

Comment: @user2096518: Why have you asked again about the function of the third parameter? It was answered very well in your previous question [*What is the third parameter to Text::JaroWinkler::strcmp95 for?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015280/). It is an irritation when people don't bother researching a question before posting it on Stack Overflow, but to ignore an answer to your *own question* is unforgiveable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try user-written `strgroup` from SSC for matching using [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). It comes with a another command called `levenshtein` that you can use to do this. Some toy code to give you an idea:

```
ssc install strgroup

input str8 names
Bob
James
Jim
Jameson
end

gen james = "James"

levenshtein names james, gen(LD)
```

You can then sort by LD to get an idea what might work well in your case.

The other way would be to do this, which creates groups for you:

```
strgroup names , gen(group) threshold(0.5)
```

and play around with the threshold.

I don't think a standard exists and these procedures will still entail lots of manual work.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion!  I had not known about this, and will definitely consider going with it as I prefer a Stata solution.  Do you know how it compares to the Jaro-Winkler distance?  That is, the pros and cons between the two?

Comment: I am not sure how they compare in theory or practice. I never really worked with JW. Another approach is to try Google Refine. They offer several string matching algorithms for reconciliation.

Comment: Upon doing further research . . . it looks like Jaro-Winkler is specifically designed to be good for names whereas Levenshtein is good for general typographical errors in strings.  And since I'm dealing with names I'm not sure I should go the route of Levenshtein.  In addition, Levenshtein does not give a probability does it?  It just says the number of characters that must be changed?

Comment: I thought that Jaro-Winkler provides a probability between 0 and 1.  Or at least provides a # between 0 and 1 which can be interpreted as a probability, no?

Comment: I meant strgroup and levenshtein. I don't know what the JW does, and I don't know that you can always interpret such numbers as probabilities. It's possible to normalize Levenshtein distance by either the longer or the shorter word length.